# git cherry-pick does not show a conflict when file does not exist?

Tags: git, version-control

I am cherry picking a commit from branch A into branch B. Branch A is many commits ahead of branch B, and I wanted to ignore a few previous commits in branch A and cherry-pick a future commit. For example, branch A has commits 1,2,3,4,5,6 and branch B has just 1,2 and I wanted to cherry-pick commit 6 from branch A into branch B. Turns out I did not realize that commit 6 changes a file introduced in commit 5(which branch B does not have). But on trying the cherry-pick of 6(to branch B), git did not show the file introduced in commit 5 as a conflict. I just lost the changes made in that file when I cherry-picked commit 6. Was that expected? Am I doing it wrong?

The command I ran was just "git cherry-pick <commit-id>"

Comment: You have conflicts when a commit that you are cherry-picking try to overwrite an existing file and the "automatic merge" cannot be used. If you had no file, there is no conflict: the automatic merge determines that the new file is the one to keep. (If I understood the idea).

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well enough. The problem is that it did not even keep the new file. It just did not find the file(introduced in commit 5) to apply the changes(introduced in commit 6), and did nothing. The file just disappeared from the commit.

Comment: This is weird. I found that git actually created a new file with both changes of commit 5 and 6(ie the final state of commit 6 for that file) in a totally different directory in my tree, with a totally different file name. It created a file "src/test/resources/RefreshedJarClassV2.txt" while the original file in question was called "Constants.java". What is happening!

Comment: If everything went right, a conflict message should have been raised saying that `deleted by us: foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the commit `6` has the path/file `src/test/resources/RefreshedJarClassV2.txt` which is not exist on branch `B`, when you cherry-pick commit `6` to branch `B`. there will show **unmerged paths** and you should mark this path to current working directory. Details steps as below:

If you have already cherry-pick commit `6` on branch `B` as below graph,

```
1---2---6'          Branch B
     \
      3---4---5---6 Branch A
```

you should reset branch `B` as the original by:

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard <commit id for 2>
```

Then the branch structure will looks like the original:

```
1---2               Branch B
     \
      3---4---5---6 Branch A
```

Now cherry-pick commit `6` again:

```
git cherry-pick <commit id for 6>
git add .
git cherry-pick --continue
```

And the path and file `src/test/resources/RefreshedJarClassV2.txt` will show in branch `B`.